# Form is never valid with WTForms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask-WTF form for sign in.  Apparently the form is never valid, no matter what I enter "success" is never printed.  Why isn't my form validating?

```
class loginForm(Form):
    email = EmailField('email', validators=[InputRequired("Please enter your email address."), Email("Please enter a valid email address.")])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired("Please enter your password.")])

@app.route('/sign-in', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signIn():
    form = loginForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print 'success'
        return redirect('/')
    return render_template('signIn.html')
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="/sign-in">
    {{ form.email(placeholder='Email', class="textBox") }}
    {{ form.password(placeholder='Password', class="textBox") }}
    <button onclick="submit()">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask-WTF [adds a CSRF protection field](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.14.2/csrf.html#html-forms).  If it's not present, the CSRF validation will fail, and the form will be invalid.  Use [`form.hidden_tag()`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/v0.14.2/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.hidden_tag) to include any hidden fields in your form (including the CSRF field).

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    ...
```

---

In general, if a form is not validating, you should check `form.errors` after calling `validate` to see what's wrong.

You don't see the error since you're not rendering that field (or rendering the errors for any fields in this case, but that wouldn't help with this issue).  If you ran in a debugger and examined `form.errors`, you would see that there was indeed a ["CSRF token missing"](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/form.py#L110) error.